# HTML, on click event, how to get the button text

Tags: html

How to get the button text or its innerHTML and use it inside the page, by not using its "name"

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">my text</button>

<script>
     function myFunction() {
      alert(my.text or innerHTML);
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `innerText` for that, like this:

```js
document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', e => {
  alert(e.target.innerText)
})
```

```html
<button id="myButton">
  Test button
</button>
```

Comment: Or [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) Note the [differences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#differences_from_innertext) between `.textContent` and `.innerText`: _"Moreover, since `innerText` takes CSS styles into account, reading the value of `innerText` triggers a reflow to ensure up-to-date computed styles. (Reflows can be computationally expensive, and thus should be avoided when possible.) "_

Answer (score 1):

The function in the `onclick` attribute can pass the element to the function as an argument using `this`. The `innerText` or `innerHTML` property of that element is then referenced directly from it as shown in the snippet.

```html
<button onclick="myFunction(this)">my text</button>

<script>
     function myFunction(element) {
      alert(element.innerText);
     }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, now that I got the innerText how can I pass it to the other page using C# on web app?